# perl regular expression finding pattern only in the front of the text

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose there is a text like this:

```
|-SAMPLE-D2
|---SAMPLE-D1
|---SAMPLE3
```

I want to count the number of "-" after |.
I tried to parse that by using the following regular expression in perl

```
$count=()= /-/g;
```

but this is problematic because the first two has "-" somewhere else in the text as well as in the front. How should I form my regex or use other function in perl to get the number of "-" right after "|"?

Comment: `/^|(-*)/`, then get the length of $1?

Comment: @MarcB I assume you meant `/^\|(-*)/` or `/^[|](-*)/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex to match the dashes after the starting `|`:
`/^\|([\-]*)/`

Comment: You don't need to escape the `-` or the character class.

Comment: No, it's not incorrect just unnecessary and regexp can be complicated enough.

Comment: You do have to escape `|` though.

Answer (score 1):

To count dashes that are not preceded by a letter, use a [negative look-behind assertion](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlretut#Looking_ahead_and_looking_behind).

```
$count = () = /(?<!\w)-/g
```

Answer (score 1):

If the vertical line only ever comes at the start you can get the string of repeating minuses with:

```
my ($match) = $txt =~ /^\|(-*)/;
```

The brackets around $match cause the captured portion of the regex to be put into it

then get the number of minuses using

```
my $minus_count = length($match || '');
```

The

> || '')

bit

Initialises $match if the regex above found no matches at all, to stop length moaning about uninitialised variables (if you have warnings on)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you can count in Regex directly but you can extract capture groups and do a simple arithmetic with their string lengths:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
my $inFile = $ARGV[0];
open(FILEHANDLE, "<", $inFile) || die("Could not open file ".$inFile);
my @fileLines = <FILEHANDLE>;
my $lineNo = 0;
my $rslt;

foreach my $line(@fileLines) {
    chomp($line);
    $line =~ s/^\s+//;
    $line =~ s/\s+$//;
    $lineNo++;
    print "\n".$lineNo." = <".$line.">";
    if($line =~ m/^\|-+(.+)/) {
        my $text = $1;
        print "\n\ttext = <".$text.">";
        my $minCnt = length($line) - length($text) - 1;
        print "\n\tminus count = <".$minCnt.">";
    }
}
close(FILEHANDLE);
```

Comment: Why do you use [`chomp()`](http://p3rl/chomp) and `s/\s+$//`? Also I would like to point out that `s/^\s+|\s+$//g` is faster than having two separate substitutions.

Comment: good point but i've had experience in the past where chomp() didn't do and the s&r did.  thanks for noting